# How to use the while loop and how to use the count in the loop

Tags: java, random

This program is designed to add 2 random numbers generated by the computer, when the user answer goes wrong , the computer tells the user to try it again, by using the while loop. The program will stop once the user enters a correct number. I have to calculate the wrong count in the while loop, however, it gives me the wrong count 1 when it is the second attempt.Please be kind enough to tell me where I go wrong in the code. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class add {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int wrong = 0;

        System.out.println("What is " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + "?");
        int answer = input.nextInt();

        while (num1 + num2 != answer) {
            System.out.println("Wrong answer, Try again . " +
                    "What is  " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "? ");
            answer = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number of attemt is " + wrong);
            ++wrong;
        }
        System.out.println("You got it correct !");
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("The number of attemt is " + ++wrong);`

Comment: Swap the below statements
 System.out.println("The number of attemt is " + wrong);
            ++wrong;

Comment: The name of your class should also be Add not add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
wrong = 0
```

to

```
wrong = 1
```

wrong should probably be renamed to numberOfAttempts.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in incrementing the number the user has gotten wrong AFTER printing "You got x wrong"

Answer (score 1):

Just put `++wrong` above `System.out.println("The number of attemt is " + wrong);`

```
while (num1 + num2 != answer) {
            System.out.println("Wrong answer, Try again . " +
                    "What is  " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "? ");
            answer = input.nextInt();
            ++wrong;
            System.out.println("The number of attemt is " + wrong);

        }
```

Comment: I entered the code just the same way you did. when I enter the wrong answer , I do not get the output "number of attempt is 1 " –

Comment: @user3196297 What do you get?

Comment: I did not get the output, to be "The number of attempt is 1  " since i did not put ++ wrong and System.out.println("The number of attemt is " + wrong); right after the while statement . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `wrong` to 1 instead of 0.

```
int wrong = 1;
```

A more appropriate name for the variable would be `attempt` if you take this approach.

Comment: I initialized int wrong = 1; however; when I enter the wrong answer , I do not get the output "number of attempt is 1  "

Comment: @user3196297 this is because you print that only after you read the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment wrong before you display it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Add {
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int num1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        int num2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        int wrong = 0 ;

        System.out.println("What is " + num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + "?");
        int answer = input.nextInt();

        while (num1 + num2 != answer){
            wrong++ ;
            System.out.println("Wrong answer, Try again . What is  " + num1 +"+"+ num2 + "? " );
            answer = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number of attempt is " + wrong);

        }
        System.out.println("You got it correct !");
    }
}
```